# What type of router do I need to get computers among different ip ranges to communicate?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, wireless-router

For a LAN - with only **one** router - currently all the computers can communicate among them through the classic/default `192.168.1.x` range - it mostly through wifi - furthermore the router offers 2 ports for wired connection through RJ-45 connector.

For the current `192.168.1.x` range the computers have their ips defined as static, it without matter the OS involved for each computer - so it avoided clashing IP addresses, and is possible to add a new pc/tablet/cellphone in the network without an issue.

I need to set/define some computers in other range, let say `192.168.2.x` and `192.168.15.x` etc.
To keep simple the situation consider the following scenario:

- 192.168.1.x for PC
- 192.168.7.x for laptops
- 192.168.15.x for tablets
- 192.168.87.x for cellphones

Therefore does not matter in what network some "host" is assigned, it must be able to communicate with all the rest.

Because I am not an expert in networks and of course is possible do some research to accomplish this goal, I need first know the answer of the two following questions:

**Questions**

- What is the concept - within the networking world - of this request/inquiry?
- What section of the router's web interface do I need to look in, to configure and accomplish this goal of communication of computers among different ip ranges? - it to let me do a research for that according the specific model of my router

Remember that only there is **one** router.

**Scenario:**

I have many computers as host using VirtualBox - so there are many guest running in the same time - it for Desktop/Workstation and Server environments - so to keep a well handled control of the ips sorted and mostly to add a new ip according with the host this approach was considered

Therefore:

- if a Host has the `192.168.1.33` I want define the guests with
  `192.168.33.10` and `192.168.33.15`
- if a Host has the `192.168.1.44` I want define the guests with `192.168.44.10` and `192.168.44.15` and `192.168.44.20`

Comment: You need a managed switch and VLANs to accomplish what you want. With a simple consumer router,, trying to separate IP addresses is not particularly useful as nothing is physically accomplished.

Comment: Despite the answers below jumping to a "vlan" answer (which may be correct) ot really dependa kn WHY you want to do this and what you want to achieve.  For examole, if you just want to statically assign IP addesses in different IP ranges depending on type but dint need to impose any restrictions between devices, you can use any router and simply set the netmask to 255.255.0.0 which will allow you to assign 192.168.x.x

Comment: what are the subnet sizes (subnet masks)? 24bits (255.255.255.0)? davidgo's comment is most likely the solution to your problem.

Comment: See the _Scenario_ section added

Answer (score 1):

**(A)** VLANs: You need a managed switch and VLANs to accomplish what you want. With a simple consumer router, trying to separate IP addresses into blocks is not particularly useful as nothing is physically accomplished.

If you need a new router to accomplish your work, one that can implement VLANs may help you set up the blocks you want.  It is probably easier with a managed switch separate from the router.

The consumer and entry level commercial routers I know of and have used do not have a facility to set up blocks of IP addresses, except by using VLANs

**(B)** Much easier will be Static IP Reservations. If your router can manage Static IP Reservations (mine can and indeed quite a number can), you can associate key device IP and their Network Card MAC address so that such devices can connect by DHCP and get the predetermined IP address. This can be a useful concept and will keep the same devices always with the same IP.

In an ordinary router, Static IP Reservation is much more useful and much easier than trying to setup IP blocks.  As I noted, no consumer router I know of has this capability.

Comment: I haven't tried it but what about a router with one of those router firmwares like ddwrt?

Comment: You may wish to get a router that can do Static IP reservations. Without that, it is much harder to manage long term.

Comment: A)I am not the OP!  B)He says in his question that his router can assign static IP addresses to his computers and that he is doing that. C)You didn't address what I asked you in comment.  "what about a router with one of those router firmwares like ddwrt?"

Comment: Assigning and tracking static IP addresses is more troublesome than Static IP Reservation overall.   Once set up devices can be set up for DHCP which is much simpler at the device level

Comment: well, putting aside how he manages his static IPs, maybe there's some router hardware out there that either supports multiple network ranges , or would with ddwrt.. that said, googling it seems people use VLANs nowadays, (as you mentiob, VLANs), either the "router" having it or this link https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2307036-is-it-possible-to-configure-a-router-with-multiple-ip-subnets  one guy mentions this switch "Cisco 3750G models on eBay for about $60" maybe there is a Gigabit version reasonably priced?

Comment: When you set up (and then manage) IP, Subnet Mask, Gateway, DNS servers for each device, that is more work than just setting the MAC in a router table. That is why I suggest it. I use a CIsco router myself. so that may work for the OP. If the chosen router does VLANs - so much the better.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that all you need to do is define the router as managing
`192.168.x.x` with a netmask of `255.255.0.0`.

The router will then happily manage all the sub-networks and pass
messages from one to the other.

(Note: I think you are over-managing your network. The router's
DHCP server is perfectly capable of managing IP allocation without
duplicates. It might also be capable of assigning static IPs to
some of the computers, but no need to do that for all of them.)

Comment: See the _Scenario_ section added

Comment: The scenario is unclear - what do the guests mean here?

Comment: The Host has installed VirtualBox - the Guest is the OS running through VirtualBox - it has an ip too. Therefore you can have your main PC/Laptop and running VirtualBox with other OS at real time. So you have practically 2 computers in the network with 2 different ips - therefore in my case there are many computers (host) running each one many Guests at real time

Answer (score 0):

Questions

**What is the concept - within the networking world - of this request/inquiry?**

This will be covered under VLAN (as mentioned in previous answers) & Subnetting

**What section of the router's web interface do I need to look in, to configure and accomplish this goal of communication of computers among different ip ranges? - it to let me do a research for that according the specific model of my router**

This depends on your router Model and make, and If at all possible on your router it
mostly should be in the Security/LAN config section.